# How can I get the user altitude from an iPhone using Unity 3D?

Tags: c#, unity

I can see in the [Unity 3D documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LocationInfo.html) that its possible to get the altitude of the user from their iPhone, but I cannot figure out how to actually do it.

I try this code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Altitude : MonoBehaviour {

    void Start () {
        Input.location.Start();
    }

    void Update () {
        Debug.Log (LocationInfo.altitude);
    }
}
```

and I get this error:

> Assets/Altitude.cs(11,41): error CS0120: An object reference is
>   required to access non-static member
>   `UnityEngine.LocationInfo.altitude'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LocationInfo is a struct so you need an instance of it to access its members. You can find a populated instance under (`LocationService.lastData`)[http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LocationService-lastData.html] or `Input.location.lastData` references `LocationService.lastData`.

Meaning you can get the `altitude` like this:

```
void Start ()
{
    Input.location.Start();
}

void Update () {
    //lastData is an instance of LocationInfo
    Debug.Log (Input.location.lastData.altitude);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I don't understand what a struct is, but you answered my question and it works! :)